# version `libssl.so.10' not found

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linker, shared-libraries

On Ubuntu 18.04 with `apt install` I installed `libssl1.0.0` and `libssl1.0-dev`.

The following shared objects are available:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
```

Set the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the previous path:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Created the following symbolic links:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10
```

Now this is what I have:

```
$ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: symbolic link to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0

$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeeaddb000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f28054fc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f280510b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2804f07000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2805ba7000)

$ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0d054641049b9747c05d030262295dfdfdd3055d, stripped

$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff3971000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f446f2b1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f446eec0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f446ecbc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f446f95c000)
```

So, at this point the dependencies for the library I will use are met.
When I try to validate that, I get issues such as `` version `libssl.so.10' not found ``.

```
$ file libpjsua2.so
libpjsua2.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=9481ccc9a0bbfe937ebb1dbc40002af55c2b424c, not stripped

$ ldd libpjsua2.so
./libpjsua2.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by ./libpjsua2.so)
./libpjsua2.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC' not found (required by ./libpjsua2.so)
./libpjsua2.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by ./libpjsua2.so)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc83691000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0d98395000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f0d9812d000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f0d97cea000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0d97ae2000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0d978c3000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f0d975bc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0d9721e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0d97006000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0d96c15000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0d98d91000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0d96a11000)
```

I would like to highlight that appears somehow it's able to resolve some `.so`:

```
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f0d9812d000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f0d97cea000)
```

There is a way for me to fix this? So `libpjsua2.so` is usable.

Comment: "There is a way for me to fix this? So libpjsua2.so is usable." - Yes, just obtain (somehow) the **actual** `libssl.so.10` library, not the one created by renaming (via symlink) the `libssl.so.1` library. Note, that the *major* library version normally represents **binary compatibility**: the libraries with different major versions - 1 and 10 - are not binary compatible. It could also be that `libssl.so.1` and `libssl.so.10` are actually compatible but just use different version scheme. But still you cannot reuse the one instead of another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shared library `libpjsua2.so` is designed for the version of OpenSSL shipped by Red Hat, CentOS, or Fedora, while you're trying to use a version built for Ubuntu.  This won't work because the SONAME is different, as well as the symbol versioning.

There isn't any way to make this work, so you'll either need to use a shared library compiled for an Ubuntu (or Debian) system or run your program on the system the shared library was compiled for.  Note that both Debian and Ubuntu ship a package called `libpjsua2`, so installing that may meet your needs.

You *could* theoretically copy the relevant OpenSSL version from the intended operating system, but doing so will likely involve a bunch of other broken shared libraries, and you will probably not be happy with the result.

Comment: Impressive just changed the Linux from Debian/Ubuntu to CentOS. Installed the `openssl` and `compat-openssl` and this error disappeared.
Thanks very much @bk2204